# Python Count the number of substring in list from other string list without duplicates

Tags: python, string, list

I have two list:

```
main_list = ['Smith', 'Smith', 'Roger', 'Roger-Smith', '42']
master_list = ['Smith', 'Roger']
```

I want to count the number of times I find a string from master_list in a string of main_list without counting two times the same item.

Example: for the two lists above, the result of my function should be 4. 'Smith' can be retrieved 3 times in main_list. 'Roger can be found 2 times but as 'Smith' was already found in 'Roger-Smith', this one doesn't count anymore, so 'Roger' is just count as 1 which make 4 in total.

The function I wrote for know is below but I think there is a faster way to do it:

```
def string_detection(master_list, main_list):
    count = 0
    for substring in master_list:
        temp = list(main_list)
        for string in temp:
            if substring in string:
                main_list.remove(string)
                count+=1
    return count
```

Comment: for big lists this gets quite tricky

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A one liner

```
>>>sum(any(m in L for m in master_list) for L in main_list)
4
```

Iterate over `main_list` and check if `any` of the values from `master_list` are in that string. This leaves you with a list of bool values. It will stop after it finds one and so adds only one to the count for each string. Conveniently `sum` counts all the `True`s to give you the count.

Comment: I don't think you are looking up anything in `master_list` or `main_list`. These are just loops, aren't they? I'm not aware of loops over sets being faster. Nice generator trick, though.

Comment: correct. The only `in` operation is the substring check which wouldn't benefit from a set. Removed that bit as its patently untrue, but given it was a bonus anyway doesn't affect the correctness of the answer itself. Good catch thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pandas` (which provide fast vectorized operations) with `str.contains` and `sum()`

```
import pandas as pd
main_list = pd.Series(['Smith', 'Smith', 'Roger', 'Roger-Smith', '42'])
master_list = ['Smith', 'Roger']
count = main_list.str.contains('|'.join(master_list)).sum()
```

Comment: Are you sure this is faster though?

Comment: OP needs to get the `count`

Answer (score 2):

You can do it other way around. Create list that will contain only elements from `main_list` that have substring from `master_list`

```
temp_list = [ string for string in main_list if any(substring in string for substring in master_list)]
```

Now `temp_list` looks like this:

```
['Smith', 'Smith', 'Roger', 'Roger-Smith']
```

So the length of `temp_list` is your answer.

Answer (score 2):

What about this

```
main_list = ['Smith', 'Smith', 'Roger', 'Roger-Smith', '42']
master_list = ['Smith', 'Roger']

print len([word for word in main_list if any(mw in word for mw in master_list)])
```

Answer (score 1):

This would do it:

```
main_list = ['Smith', 'Smith', 'Roger', 'Roger-Smith', '42']
master_list = ['Smith', 'Roger']

i = 0
for elem in main_list:
    if elem in master_list:
        i += 1
        continue
    for master_elem in master_list:
        if master_elem in elem:
            i += 1
            break

print(i) # i = 4
```

The code above counts `'Roger-Smith'` as 1, if you want it to count as multiple, remove the `break`.

Answer (score 1):

If your master_list is not expected to be huge, one way to do it is with regex:

```
import re

def string_detection(master_list, main_list):
    count = 0
    master = re.compile("|".join(master_list))
    for entry in main_list:
        if master.search(entry):
            count += 1
    return count
```